# The Access Token Has Been Obtained For the Wrong Audience

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to CRUD Logic App workflows programmatically using the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflows). To do so, I need a JWT attached in the `Authorization` header of each request.

I'm trying to set up access between our Azure AD and our Logic App to allow for these operations but cannot seem to get the token to authenticate.

For resources there is:

- Logic App
- App Registration with a client id/secret

I've generated an application ID `api://X` and have used that to generate a token with this request:

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: myClientId
client_secret: myClientSecret
scope: api://X/.default
audience: https://management.azure.com
```

`POST`ing to:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/app_guid_here/oauth2/v2.0/token`

which successfully creates a token, but not one that is accepted. When decoding the token, the `aud` field is the application ID `GUID`, which throws the following error when using it to `PUT` a workflow CRUD operation to the LogicApp REST API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationTokenAudience",
        "message": "The access token has been obtained for wrong audience or resource 'api://X'. It should exactly match with one of the allowed audiences 'https://management.core.windows.net/','https://management.core.windows.net','https://management.azure.com/','https://management.azure.com'."
    }
}
```

I'm certain that I've missed something here, I'm very new to managing identity this way so frankly I'm a little lost.

Have I missed a step allowing access to the management API via the app registration? Do I need to add extra permissions elsewhere?

Frankly all I need is a way to generate these JWTs to authorize requests to the Management API, the specific setup to do so is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you can do is register the resource in the azure ad and acquire
  the tokens from the azure ad and then pass them to the desired
  resource.
- Here we need a `tenetid` and `clientid` for acquiring the tokens. Now you can get both the id from the portal the tenent id will be displayed under basic info and the client id will be under the register app section.

using msal for python:

```
from  msal  import  PublicClientApplication
import  sys
client_id =  '<client-id>'
tenant_id = '<tenant-id>'
scopes = [ '2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d/.default' ]
app = PublicClientApplication
            (
                client_id = client_id,
                authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant_id
            )
acquire_tokens = app.acquire_token_interactive
                            (
                                scopes = scopes
                            )
```

Thus after registering your app in azure ad you can get the tokens which can authenticate any registered azure resource including apim.

**Reference:**
[getting azure ad tokens using msal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token)

[how to get client id and tenent id](https://geeksarray.com/blog/get-azure-subscription-tenant-client-id-client-secret)